# Use CI hook to set common variables

Tags: codeigniter

I have several common variables which I want to set using a hook.  For example I have a post_controller_constructor hook, inside this I want to perform some logic to set the users home folder:

```
public function post_controller_constructor() {             
  $home_folder = isset($_SESSION['hf']) ? $_SESSION['hf'] : NULL;

  // Check whether the homefolder value has been set            
  $home_folder = isset($_SESSION['hf']) ? base_url($_SESSION['hf']) : base_url('default');
}
```

But how do I pass the resulting variable $home_folder back to my controllers?

Comment: Have you looked at base controllers? http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function post_controller_constructor() {             
  $home_folder = isset($_SESSION['hf']) ? $_SESSION['hf'] : NULL;

  // Check whether the homefolder value has been set            
  $home_folder = isset($_SESSION['hf']) ? base_url($_SESSION['hf']) : base_url('default');

  $CI =& get_instance();

  $CI->home_folder = $home_folder;

}
```

Would do it.

Comment: Just one little addition. When you want to use this `home_folder` in controllers. Use it with `$this` for instance `$this->home_folder`