# How to get a functiona automatically load in every function of controllers in COdeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a sample script

```
<?php
class level_price extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }

    function index()
    {
         if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
            redirect(base_url().'admin.php/login');
        }
        $data['users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS user FROM user_table")->result_array();
        $data['pro_users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
        $this->load->model('level_model');
        $data['level_list']=$this->level_model->get_all_level();
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('level_price');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }


    function add_level()
      {
          if(!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
              {
                redirect(base_url().'admin.php/login');
              }
         $this->load->model('level_model');
         $data['users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS user FROM user_table")->result_array();
         $data['pro_users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
         if(count($_POST))
           {
              $data['msg']=$this->level_model->add_level();
           }
         $this->load->view('header',$data);
         $this->load->view('add_level',$data);
         $this->load->view('footer');
      }

      function edit_level($id){
           if(!isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
            redirect(base_url().'admin.php/login');
        }
            $this->load->model('level_model');
            $data['level_id'] = $id;
            $data['users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS user FROM user_table")->result_array();
            $data['pro_users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
            if(count($_POST))
             {
              $data['msg']=$this->level_model->edit_level($id);

             }
            $data['level_info'] = $this->level_model->get_level($id);
            $this->load->view('header',$data);
            $this->load->view('edit_level',$data);
            $this->load->view('footer');

      }
}

?>
```

as you can see i have these two lines always in every function

```
$data['users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS user FROM user_table")->result_array();
$data['pro_users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
```

now i want a substitute such that automatically to have these two functions called

say something i define a function which returns the array

and when i just write this script

`echo pro_user()`, then it displays the pro_user quantity

say in the application/admin/config/autoload.php

i have added this script

```
$autoload['model'] = array('special_model');
```

the function in the special_model is like this

```
function  pro_user()
        {
            $data['pro_users']=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
            echo $data['pro_users']['pro_user'];
        }
```

in the view php like i want something like this want to write something like this

```
<a data-rel="tooltip" title="" class="well span3 top-block" href="#">
                    <span class="icon32 icon-color icon-star-on"></span>
                    <div>Pro Members</div>
                    <div><?php $this->special_model->pro_user();?></div>
                    <span class="notification green">4</span>
                </a>
```

but i am getting the error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: pro_user

Filename: models/special_model.php

Line Number: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define these in the ci_controller , every controller extends that so you will have them in every controller function as well

go to

```
system/core/codeigniter.php
```

cahnge

```
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;
```

to

```
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;
        public $pro_users;
        public $any_thing ;
```

and then at the end of `__construct()`  function in  the same page

add

```
$this->pro_users = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*)AS pro_user FROM user_table WHERE membership_type <>0")->result_array();
```

now in every controller you can have that by calling

```
$this->pro_users
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write a codeigniter hook and set the value of a variable with that function, and then pass that variable to the view. Calling model functions in views breaks the MVC pattern.

You can use `post_controller` or `post_controller_constructor`, more info:

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html
- [Use CI hook to set common variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127804/use-ci-hook-to-set-common-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to write a helper and load it in autoload.

e.g

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function alphabetArray() {
    $alph = array();
    for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
        array_push($alph, chr($i));
    }
    return $alph;
}
```

now anyehre in code I can call (code from view)

```
<?php
     echo "|";
     foreach (alphabetArray() as $alphabet) {
     echo '<a href="#"> '.$alphabet.' </a> |';
}
?>
```

As you can see my `alphabetArray()` function is "global" function and it can be used in models/views/controllers