# HOOK SET-UP PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, hook, var

I have this in my "hooks.php" file

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
  'class'    => 'My_hook',
  'function' => 'post_controller_constructor',
  'filename' => 'my_hook.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks',
  'params'   => array()
);
```

this is in my file "my_hook.php"
`

```
class My_hook {
  public function post_controller_constructor() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $matrix = $CI->user->privileges($_SESSION['user_id']);
    $CI->load->vars(array('matrix' => $matrix));
  }
}
```

So what and where do I put in my Controllers and where to get the array that i hope is being produced?

Comment: If you are using a framework (CodeIgniter?) please use the tag for it.

Comment: Could you explain what it is you want to get in your controller?

Comment: @bland_dan , I hope that when i put the varaible "$matrix" It gives me the value " Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => ? [privilege] => ? [team] =>????(????? ) ) "

Comment: I had a similar problem last year and got the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127804/use-ci-hook-to-set-common-variables